# Should you downvote duplicates without searching for the search terms first?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Should a question with unique wording, which doesn't yield useful search results unless you already know the answer be downvoted or just silently closed ? How do you point out to other people voting that the question is a useful duplicate and increases searchability of the question ?

Should you flag as dup and add a comment about searchablity to point out to other users ? Is it useful behaviour to upvote and counter downvotes to prevent deletion if you think it adds to the site ?

Comment: 1) Counter voting is not good, since you then don't vote on the content of the post anymore 2) Closing and voting are two different things and shouldn't be mixed together.

Answer (score 6):

If *you* feel that the question is well researched, clear, and useful, despite being a duplicate, then you're more than welcome to vote accordingly.

You should not concern yourself with how others vote.  If others feel that the question wasn't well researched, even if you do, then they are free to reflect that opinion.  You have your vote, and they have theirs.

You should not upvote a post because you don't like that someone else downvoted a post.  You should vote on a post based on whether or not you think it's useful, regardless of whether others think it's useful or not.  You certainly shouldn't be upvoting content that you personally feel doesn't merit an upvote, just to prevent deletion.

Comment: On another note, do duplicate questions even get deleted by downvotes after 30 days like normal questions or do they stick around forever ?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful They are not automatically deleted for having a negative score.  Users would need to vote to delete them.

Comment: @Servy Duplicates are actually subject to the 30/365-day roombas. Only the 9-day roomba excludes duplicates. +1 to your answer though.